# How to unload Firefox tabs (so they'll reload when activated)?

Tags: firefox, memory, browser-tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I unload a tab manually?](https://superuser.com/questions/461055/how-can-i-unload-a-tab-manually)

If Firefox is running with a couple of tabs open and it's switched into Private Mode (an empty Firefox window appears) and then switched back, all the tabs are restored, but they're unloaded. They're only loaded when activated. If one of those tabs would be a Youtube page, the video would only be loaded and played as soon as the tab is manually activated by the user (not right after switching back from Private Mode).

**Is it possible to unload all Firefox tabs (except for the active one) on demand?**

The idea is that I often have a ton of tabs open and while I don't need all of them at the time, I don't want to close them, because I will need them later. When they're all unloaded, Firefox has a reason to release some memory, so it only eats 500M instead of 1.5G because only one tab/window needs to be in RAM (ok, switching into Private Mode and back does not seem to release any memory (maybe it will in a future version) and yes, I know, addons may also be a reason, but anyway).

Comment: *Restart All Tabs* as described in the linked question should do what you want. Let me know if (and why!) this isn't the case so this question can be reopened.